# Is it possible for Excel print consistently with any printer? avoid awkward page breaks?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Our organization has a hundred printer makes and models.  We all use Office 2007, and we all print to letter size (8.5" x 11") paper.  However, when someone distributes an Excel spreadsheet across our organization, it prints with awkward page breaks in many or most of our users.

For example, Sue sets her worksheet to print all in one page, then saves it and emails it to Becky and Anne.  When Becky opens the email and clicks "Print", the printer puts out 2 or 4 pages.  More-so, when Becky and Anne print to the same physical printer, their printouts' page breaks are different.

- It is especially annoying if the worksheet has charts and graphs.

Is it possible to do something on Sue's end to prevent this?  Is there anything that can be done?  We spend enormous time "fixing" every attachment prior to printing.  Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the various users are simply printing the worksheet without adding any additional data, I highly recommend that the originating user export or print the document as a PDF.

Obviously you won't have the ability to work with the data in its native format, but you'll avoid the hassle of printer configuration as a PDF describes a printer page more accurately than Excel does natively.